# Auto populate Fields External Module not functioning correctly

Tags: redcap

**What I'm using/Goal:**

I'm using an external module to autopopulate our patient registration form across events. My goal for using this is that when we use a report that contains data from multiple events, the name, DOB etc. populates for that row without someone having to re-fill out the patient registration form for each event.

**What's not working:** it is not autopopulating the patient information across events

As you can see in the below screenshot the initial (the first event) has the DOB and name (blacked out) but the sequential events (Procedure 1-7) doesn't have those.

[image]

**Troubleshooting:**

I double checked that I am using the '@DEFAULT-FROM-PREVIOUS-EVENT' action tag to use this external module but yet there are still blanks when I look at the report. The other strange part is that the bubbles/status icon on some of the procedures for patient registration are gray but for others are red.

[image][image]

If I click into the gray bubble ones for the event, the name, DOB etc. DOES show up there but not in the reports.

What am I missing here or doing incorrectly? Is there a better way of accomplishing my end goal (be able to see patient registration information across events in a report without having to fill it out each time?)

Documentation here for the external module: https://github.com/ctsit/auto_populate_fields